# Why assembly function called from C++ give different result in flags if addition made with two variables or one variable and one numeric literal?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, flags

Please help me if someone can!

I've written a 3 row Assembly code to get back the value of RFLAGS:

```
PUBLIC x64rflags
.code
; Caller C++ function prototype: unsigned long long int x64rflags();
x64rflags PROC     
    pushfq          ; RFLAGS into stack
    pop rax         ; RAX = RFLAGS
    ret    
x64rflags ENDP
End
```

which I use in a C++ library to check flags from C++ programs:

```
//The RFLAGS query function. Result in unsigned long long int value.
extern "C"
{
    unsigned long long int x64rflags();
}

//The FLAGS bits decimal values
enum
{
    FLAGS_CF = 1, //Carry
    FLAGS_PF = 4, //Parity
    FLAGS_AF = 16, //Adjust (Auxiliary carry)
    FLAGS_ZF = 64, //Zero
    FLAGS_SF = 128, //Sign
    FLAGS_TF = 256, //Trap
    FLAGS_IF = 512, //Interrupt enable
    FLAGS_DF = 1024, //Direction
    FLAGS_OF = 2048, //Overflow
    FLAGS_IOPL_LOW = 4096, //I/O privilege level low bit
    FLAGS_IOPL_HIGH = 8192, //I/O privilege level high bit
    FLAGS_NT = 16384, //Nested task
    FLAGS_RF = 65536, //Resume
    FLAGS_VM = 131072, //Virtual 8086 mode
    FLAGS_AC = 262144, //Alignment Check
    FLAGS_VIF = 524288, //Virtual interrupt
    FLAGS_VIP = 1048576, //Virtual interrupt Pending
    FLAGS_ID = 2097152, //CPUID available
};

//The compare function of RFLAGS and inpected values
bool flagschk(unsigned long long int flags, unsigned long long int flagsToChk)
{
    if (flagsToChk == (flagsToChk & flags))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here my C++ testprogram:

```
#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <x64rflags.h>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long int ulli;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1250); //ANSI Central European; Central European (Windows)

    ulli ullia, ullib, ullir, actrflags;
    std::string stro1, stro2;

    ullia = 0xffffffffffffffff;
    ullib = 1;
    ullir = ullia + ullib; //CF
    actrflags = x64rflags(); //CALL THE RFLAGS RETURNER ASM FUNCTION
    printf("1 Result: %llu\n", ullir);
    stro1 = "1 The value of actrflags: ";
    stro2 = std::to_string(unsigned long long int(actrflags));
    stro1.append(stro2);
    stro1.append("\n");
    printf(stro1.c_str());


    if(flagschk(actrflags, FLAGS_CF))
    {
        printf("1 condparam = TRUE\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("1 condparam = FALSE\n\n");
    }
//*/
    ullia = 0xffffffffffffffff;
    ullir = ullia + 1; //CF
    actrflags = x64rflags(); //CALL THE RFLAGS RETURNER ASM FUNCTION
    printf("2 Result: %llu\n", ullir);
    stro1 = "2 The value of actrflags: ";
    stro2 = std::to_string(unsigned long long int(actrflags));
    stro1.append(stro2);
    stro1.append("\n");
    printf(stro1.c_str());


    if(flagschk(actrflags, FLAGS_CF))
    {
        printf("2 condparam = TRUE\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("2 condparam = FALSE\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that it gives me diffrent result on the two probe.
The first which use variables work as expected: Raise the Carry and Give back "TRUE"

The second which use one variable and one numeric literal don't raise Carry.

[image]

Additional info:
The Assembly code compiled by ml64 with option /c
The C++ code written in Code::Blocks, compiled with MSVC 2019.
The program running on Intel x64Arch (core i7).
The programs (in theory) use the default (x64 ABI) calling conventions.
If I don't use the "=" in the adding expression before the rflags query that not work in both case. (I guess then the MSVC handling the addition as "NOP" and give back the last carry independently from the addition...)

Someone can explain what couse this anomaly?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but instead of `if (condition) return true; else return false`; you could just have `return condition;`

Comment: Did you look at the assembly code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any expectation about how the compiler chooses to implement the C `+` operator in terms of asm is unfounded.  Some tuning options could make it prefer `lea` instead of `add` which doesn't set flags.  (For GCC this is in fact the case with `-mtune=atom`).

With optimization enabled, it might do it in a different order, not right before that non-inline function call.

**Or for `+1` specifically, MSVC might have chosen [`inc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/inc) which doesn't modify CF.**  That looks like the case here, given that your FLAGS result differs only in the low bit.  ([CF is the lowest bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)).  For that bit, you're reading whatever value happened to be left in CF before the `inc`.  The other bits are written by `inc`.

You can check the compiler-generated asm by single-stepping with a debugger, or put it on https://godbolt.org/

---

And there's also no reason to assume that that FLAGS are still set from the asm for `+` by the time execution reaches your function call.  Even inline asm can't reliably do this.  **If you want to read FLAGS from `add`, the `add` needs to be in your asm, not compiler-generated.**

The optimizer does *not* consider the FLAG results of previous C statements to be an input to function calls, or an observable side-effect at all (except for compiler-generated code that intentionally reads FLAGS results, e.g. `jnz` after an add to implement `if(foo)`)